# Android App context null in Activity.onCreate()

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, android-context

This code in Activity

```
public void onCreate(Bundle bundle)
{
    super.onCreate(bundle);
    DisplayMetrics metrics = App.getAppContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics(); //crash
}
```

sometimes produces a `NullPointerException`.

This is the custom App class:

```
public class App extends Application
{
    private static Context context;

    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        context = getApplicationContext();
    }

    public static Context getAppContext()
    {
        return context;
    }
}
```

How can the `NullPointerException` be fixed?

Answer (score 3):

Replace:

```
DisplayMetrics metrics = App.getAppContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
```

with:

```
DisplayMetrics metrics = getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
```

Not only do you not need the `Application` here, anything GUI-related should be using an `Activity` anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `App.getAppContext()`

just

```
 DisplayMetrics metrics = getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
```

or

```
DisplayMetrics metrics = this.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
```

or

```
DisplayMetrics metrics = getApplicationContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
```